# Shell Script Printing in table format

Tags: shell

I am trying to print set of values in table format using shell script . The table has n rows and 4 columns. I tried the following piece of code.

```
btfield=`grep -i -r ^"diag.* <string>" *.txt |awk '{print $5}'|cut -d+ -f 1 |sort -u`
ipaddr=''
i=0
format="%10s\t%10s\t%10s   \n"
echo "| Function  " "     |         IP         |"  "    occurences     |"  
for a in $btfield
do
  b=`grep -i -r ^"diag.* <string>" *.txt |grep  -i $a |cut -d: -f 1|cut -d_ -f 2|cut -d't' -f 1`
  noOcc=`grep -i -r ^"diag.* backtrace" *.txt |grep  -i $a|wc -l`
  #echo $b
  ipaddr[i]=${b}
  printf "$format"  $a  ${ipaddr[i]} $noOcc
  i=$((i+1))
  #echo $i
done
```

The above piece of code finds distinct fields from various files and prints according to the format specifier.

But what I am seeing is misaligned form of output. Is there any way to print the values in table format ? The column width is fixed and if the value in cell exceeds the width it must wrap itself.

```
Sample output:

|       reason          |        STB IP         |        occurences     |
printf     142.25.1.100.   142.25.1.100.   
142.25.1.102.   142.25.1.105.   192.168.1.100.   
192.168.1.100.  192.168.1.100.  192.168.1.100.   
192.168.1.106.           9                   
class_consol      142.25.1.105.   192.168.1.103.   
         2                                   
getChar   182.168.1.102.           1   
     maindat      142.25.1.103.            1   
_XN52getappdatafrom3EZN2232_iPjj     142.25.1.103.   142.25.1.103.   
182.168.1.106.
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead of using `echo`, use the **`printf`** command.

You can use `%s` for a string and `%d` for an integer:

```
printf "%20s %8d %s\n" "$string1" $int1 "$unbounded_string"
```

You can space according to your screen, by using `%20s` for using 20 characters for the string, `%8d` for the integer.

Format control options are also available:

`\n`: newline

`\t`: tab (horizontal)

`\v`: tab (vertical)

Answer (score 5):

Just making clear that comma is not needed in printf.

Everything that is to be printed should be written in double quotes and after these quotes you have to mention variables which are used inside double quotes.

*For example:*

```
name=barack
age=52
printf "My name is %s \t age is %s \n" $name $age
```

*outputs:*

```
my name is barack       age is 52
```

The exact answer to the question is (assuming values for variable are calculated correctly):

*Printing heading:*

```
printf "|\tFunction\t|\tIP\t|\toccurences\t|\n"
```

*printing values:*

```
printf "|\t%s\t|\t%s\t|\t%s\t|\n" $a  ${ipaddr[i]} $noOcc
```

Of course number of tabs (\t) depends on your length of data.